# ed invalid address macOS

Tags: ed

```
/Delete/,/endif/p
?
invalid address
/Delere/,/endif/p
?
no match
```

Does it mean it understands latin only?

```
/Dele/,/endif/p
?
invalid address
/Del/,/endif/p
?
invalid address
```

No, what am I doing wrong? I'm typing out all letters without any mistakes.

I have macOS.

The following is a sample from the file I'm editing that exhibit the same behaviour when editing it using the above `ed` command:

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Editing mappings
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Remap VIM 0 to first non-blank character
map 0 ^

" Move a line of text using ALT+[jk] or Command+[jk] on mac
nmap <M-j> mz:m+<cr>`z
nmap <M-k> mz:m-2<cr>`z
vmap <M-j> :m'>+<cr>`<my`>mzgv`yo`z
vmap <M-k> :m'<-2<cr>`>my`<mzgv`yo`z

if has("mac") || has("macunix")
  nmap <D-j> <M-j>
  nmap <D-k> <M-k>
  vmap <D-j> <M-j>
  vmap <D-k> <M-k>
endif

" Delete trailing white space on save, useful for some filetypes ;)

if has("autocmd")
    autocmd BufWritePre *.txt,*.js,*.py,*.wiki,*.sh,*.coffee :call CleanExtraSpaces()
endif
```

Comment: What are you wanting to achieve here ?  What is your input containing, what output do you want to produce ?

Comment: I wanted to delete lines between `Delete` and `endif` (including the containing lines). Because It did not work, I was just experimenting with printing them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `endif` occurs before the first `Delete`, so `ed` gets confused about the range being specified "backwards".

You will want to first find the first occurence of `Delete`, *then* apply the command from that line down to the next `endif`:

```
1,/Delete/
.,/endif/p
```

The first command will place the cursor on the first line of the file that contains the word `Delete`, and the second command will print the lines from that line down to the next line that contains the word `endif`.

---

If you were to give the same command in `vi`, it would complain with "The second address is smaller than the first", and `vim` would ask "Backwards range given, OK to swap (y/n)?" when giving the editing command `:/Delete/,/endif/p`.

`sed` would not have an issue as it looks for the first address before it starts looking for the second address (since it's a stream editor).

Answer (score 1):

Ed has a notion of "[current address](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html#Line-addressing)"; you can see it with `.n` (print the current line with its number prepended). When you open a file, it's set to the last line of the file.

If you specify an address using a regular expression, you get the next line downward of the current address that matches, wrapping around at the end of the file, so after opening a file, searches start on the first line.

Now, if you specify an address *range* with `/pattern1/,/pattern2/`, ed first searches for `pattern1` starting from the current address, then for `pattern2` starting from the current address. *The current address isn't changed between the two searches.*

So, when you search for `/Delete/,/endif/`, the first address matches line 20; then, we start from the last line again, and `endif` matches on line 18. Because the value for the first address can't exceed the value of the second one, you get an error.

The solution is to use `;` to separate the addresses:

> In a semicolon-delimited range, the current address (`.`) is set to the first address before the second address is calculated.

So you can use this:

```
/Delete/;/endif/p
```

and you get lines 20-24:

```
/Delete/;/endif/p
" Delete trailing white space on save, useful for some filetypes ;)

if has("autocmd")
    autocmd BufWritePre *.txt,*.js,*.py,*.wiki,*.sh,*.coffee :call CleanExtraSpaces()
endif
```

And to delete them, as alluded to in the comments:

```
ed infile <<'EOE'
/Delete/-;/endif/d
wq
EOE
```

This uses the address `/Delete/-` to also remove the blank line before the `Delete` line.

Comment: This had totally escaped me. Thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: @Kusalananda Finally putting the knowledge acquired through reading [Ed Mastery](https://www.tiltedwindmillpress.com/?product=ed) to good use ;)

Answer (score 0):

Need `/startrange/,/endrange/d`.  Example

```
$ cat inp
foo
Delete
these lines
endif
bar
$ ed inp
33
/Delete/,/endif/d
w
8
q
$ cat inp
foo
bar
$
```

I'd just use `sed` :

```
$ sed -i '/Delete/,/endif/d' inp
$
```